# How do I load PDFs dynamically from a PHP server?

Tags: javascript, jquery, pdf, tcpdf

I'm using TCPDF for making PDF reports. On the client side is a JavaScript/jQuery app.
On the server side is "some.php" and we are sending some parameters for filtering the database queries.

Is it possible to use:

```
$.ajax or $.post(url,{...},function(data) { //open new window with PDF result}
```

The last command in TCPDF is:

```
$pdf->output('doc.pdf','I');
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot render pdf with javascript.

There are 2 ways how I will did it:

1. do not use ajax, just send the form with values to a new window where pdf will open. do not forget to send correct content type header application/pdf.

   ```
   <form action="some.php" method="post" target="_blank">
   ...
   </form>
   ```
2. send all form values with ajax query to some.php, some.php will generate the pdf, save it to disk and return back the link to that generated pdf file. Then on ajax onSuccess you will call that link.

Comment: Deep google-ing => ajax couldn't response with file upload, so your 2 option works for me. Last help please, how to delete uploaded file on the server, or how to create temporary file (Apache+PHP)

Comment: you could setup a cron job to delete files for example after 1 day.

Answer (score 0):

Mozilla recently came up with [pdf.js](http://mozilla.github.com/pdf.js/), a JavaScript library to read PDF files.

While not being exactly what you're searching, you can derive a minimized and customized version from the included source.